# What character encoding is used for Linux configuration files?

Tags: linux, configuration, locale

A colleague was using Qt's built-in QTextStream class to rewrite the /etc/network/interfaces file on an Ubuntu system.  Part of that code included a call to QTextStream's setCodec() method, where the codec was set to UTF-8. (see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#setCodec if you're curious)

This got me wondering about what the Linux configuration files are *SUPPOSED* to be written as.  It seems like ISO 8859-1 would be the closest to what I'd consider "plain ASCII" style of text, and I would (perhaps naively) assume this to be correct since most configurations files are plain English with no need for much more than the basic alphabet, numbers and a few punctuation signs.

But then I also wonder what would someone from a non-English speaking country do if they wanted to put comments into such files using other characters that aren't in ISO-8859-. Are they just plain "out of luck" ?

There are obviously a lot of "standard" configuration files that you'd find on an Ubuntu/Linux system, e.g.

- /etc/network/interfaces
- /etc/ntp.conf
- /etc/hostname
- ...

Would anyone care to weigh in on what encoding is actually supported/expected in these sort of files ?  And where this is actually documented ?  Is it enshrined in some sort of "Linux developers manifesto" as something writers of new Linux system services should be following, and if so, where would I find a definitive source of that information ?

Comment: UTF-8 is as close to plain ASCII as is ISO-8859-1, in that both contain ASCII as a subset. Both encodings produce identical results if you restrict the text to plain ASCII. ISO-8859-1 has the problem, as you point out yourself, that ISO-8859-1 is a much more restricted encoding. IMHO, the 8-bit ISO-8859 encodings are a thing of the past and should be phased out.

Comment: If a particular service, for example the NTP daemon, is only written with ASCII in mind when it reads /etc/ntp.conf, what is going to happen if someone embeds UTF-8 non-ASCII characters (e.g. in a comment). Is it explicitly doing UTF-8 aware processing of the configuration file (by design), or is it just "dumb luck" that it works ?  That's what I'm trying to understand here.  Obviously there are a lot of "moving pieces" so I can't just read all their source code to figure this out. That's why I was looking for some sort of "recipe" document that they are all following (hopefully !)

Comment: If the program that reads the configuration file expects plain ASCII, then I would say the chance it chokes on ISO-8859 is just as big as it is with UTF-8. If the non-ASCII characters are in comments, the chance is probably quite small.

Answer (score 0):

The general Encoding can be set via the LANG environment variable, but by now nearly all Linux distros and tools have migrated to UTF-8. The main advantage for configuration files is, that any string using only ASCII characters *are* valid ASCII. So for most configuration files it doesn't really matter, since they only use those characters anyway

Comment: Does UTF-8 BOM matter on Linux system files?